# How to convert octal value to string in PHP?

Tags: php, octal

One of my webs service is responding value in octal(010), I want to use this value as key in an array.

```
$key = 010;
$a[$key] = 'test';
print_r($a);
```

Result :

```
Array
(
    [8] => test
)
```

Expected :

```
Array
(
    [010] => test
)
```

PHP is converting 010 value to 9 even I do typecasting, I tried `(string) $key` and `sprintf('%s', $key)` but no luck.

Is there anyway do we have to convert octal to string without change the value?

Comment: You could write a function that keeps the original octal as a literal string keeping the formatting. [Octal - From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) has some useful information as to how to represent octal literals. Using a lower case 'o' as a prefix would be quite clear to read and be obvious it is an octal number. And it would be easy to convert back to an octal number and PHP will leave it alone when used as a string key.

Answer (score 2):

```
$key = sprintf('%o', $key);
```

see http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php
(but then your key is a string, not an integer anymore)

edit: not sure if you want the leading 0 to be printed always

```
$key = sprintf('0%o', $key);
```

or to always get a key with three digits

```
$key = sprintf('%03o', $key);
```

Comment: It is returning 10 not 010.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP (and essentially every other language), these types of declarations are allowed, but are always converted to a decimal integer (binary internally) at compile/parse time. So when the script is running, `$key` will always be `8`. If you want to use the octal value as a key, you [need a function](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.decoct.php) that formats numbers into other bases (which will be represented as a string).

```
$num = 8;
$key = $num === 0 ? '0' : '0' . decoct(8); // works for all numbers 0 and up
$a[$key] = 'test';
print_r($a);
```

Comment: It is returning 10 not 010.

Comment: Nice catch. You need to explicitly add a `0` to make it work how you want. The only reason the zero is required when defining numbers in octal is for the parser to be able to tell unambiguously what you mean. Updated answer (note: this will work for everything except zero, which will become '00').

Comment: I have possibility to get numbers like 0010, 00020, 00001, 00012131, etc. I want solution to take care all leading zeros.

Comment: But leading zeros have no meaning. `01` is equivalent to `0000001`. How is PHP supposed to know how to format the number for you? The only solution is to strip the zeros from all the keys in advance to normalize it.